# Old school material shader (ambient, diffuse, specular)

Tags: materials

I recently migrated to the new blender and can't find the old way to use material by choosing the ambient, diffuse and specular color ([example image of what I'm looking for](https://images.app.goo.gl/dapTdfQqYimqpstJA)).
Is there a way to get it back?

*I tested to import a wavefront file and export it directly, it change the colors inside the .mtl*

Comment: Hello :). Blender Render isn't a part of Blender 2.8+. If you need it, use the official [2.79b release](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/).

Comment: Thanks Jachym! So if I understand correctly, the "Blender Render" is gone forever unless using a previous version?

Comment: Yes, that's correct :). It was replaced by Eevee, a new realtime render engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not the same, but there are similar parameters in the new eevee renderer.

Using the Specular shader you can tweak diffuse + specular color.
[image]

Via world properties -> color you can tweak the ambient color
[image]

Also accesible in shader editor:
[image]

Comment: Those parameters don't show up in the export for me though.